# Year out of Range Exception

Tags: java, sql, oracle, hibernate

I am intermittently getting an exception while saving records in database. Trigerring re-save of the same object from UI works well but not sure why do I hit the exception first. ALl date fields are good. Has anyone encountered this issue ever?

```
org.springframework.jdbc.UncategorizedSQLException: Hibernate operation: Could not execute JDBC batch update; uncategorized SQLException for SQL [insert into t_order (trade_id, product_type, trading_desk, trading_book, trader_portfolio, current_workflow_state, creation_date, trade_date, execution_time, last_modified_date, last_modified_by_sid, sales_desk_id, creator_desk_id, action, vcon_bbg_speed_dial, vcon_comments, vcon_id, vcon_status, marketer_comment, creator_sid, trader_sid, salesperson_sid, on_behalf_of_sid, cpty_id, cpty_client_code, cpty_qib_flag, instrument_id, factor, settlement_date, settlement_date_convention, linked_deal_id, price, notional, real_notional, principal, net_money, accrued_interest, price_mode, buy_sell, yield, grid_cv, total_cv, additonal_cv, markup, additional_cv_units, leg_type_string, issue_type, pair_off, client_clearing, settlement_method, invert_fx_flag, clean_price, fx_ccy, fx_rate, transaction_cost, fx_transaction_cost, fx_principal, fx_net_money, fx_accrued_interest, accrual_days, discount, revenue_cv_rate, revenue_bond_markup_rate, revenue_fx_rate, revenue_cv_total, revenue_bond_markup_total, revenue_fx_total, revenue_split_coverage, revenue_split_execution, fx_customer_branch, nack_message, trade_flat_flag, deal_region, sales_book, rdt_instrument_id, parent_transaction_id, order_id) values (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)]; SQL state [99999]; error code [17268]; Year out of range.; nested exception is java.sql.BatchUpdateException: Year out of range.
    at org.springframework.jdbc.support.AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.translate(AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.java:83)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.support.AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.translate(AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.java:80)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.support.AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.translate(AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.java:80)
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateAccessor.convertJdbcAccessException(HibernateAccessor.java:424)
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateAccessor.convertHibernateAccessException(HibernateAccessor.java:410)
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTemplate.doExecute(HibernateTemplate.java:411)
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTemplate.executeWithNativeSession(HibernateTemplate.java:374)
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTemplate.saveOrUpdate(HibernateTemplate.java:747)
    at com.jpmorgan.salesone.traderouter.dao.DealDaoImpl.saveCashDeal(DealDaoImpl.java:29)
    at com.jpmorgan.salesone.traderouter.dao.DealJSPBeanManager.saveNewCashDealBean(DealJSPBeanManager.java:106)
```

Comment: Isn't the error message obvious? It says that a value for a year is out of range. Please provide a printout of the values you send. One of those in the datetime fields are out of range...

Comment: I agree with Xabster, one of your values is not what you think it is.

Comment: @Xabster if "Year out of range" was an obvious error I wouldn't be here looking for it, probably.